# \seq_use:Nn gets ! Missing = inserted for \ifnum

Tags: expl3

My primary problem is that I'm getting "! Missing = inserted for `\ifnum`." from `\seq_use:Nn`. My secondary problem is that I'm getting unexpected terminal reads. I've tried commenting out the parentheses and deling the `\` in `\exists`, but neither helps.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xparse} % loads expl3
%See interface3.pdf

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\uqualg}{mm}
 {
   \msg_term:n{Enterring~uqualg}
    % Set option defaults
    \bool_if_exist:NTF \style_qual_parens
      {}
      {\bool_gset_false:N \style_qual_parens}
    \bool_if_exist:NTF \style_qual_paren_pairs
      {}
      {\bool_gset_false:N \style_qual_paren_pairs}
    \bool_if_exist:NTF \style_qual_subscript
      {}
      {\bool_gset_false:N \style_qual_subscript}

    \bool_if:NTF \style_qual_subscript
      {
        \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl {\\} {#1}
        \tl_show:N \l_tmpa_tl
        \bool_if:NTF \style_qual_parens
          {(\exists \sb {\l_tmpa_tl})#2}
          {\exists \sb {\l_tmpa_tl} #2}
      }
      {
      \msg_term:n{No~subscript~for~#1~}
      \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {#1}
       \msg_term:n{l_tmpa_tl=\l_tmpa_tl~}
       \msg_term:n{test~paren~pairs~}
       \bool_if:NTF \style_qual_paren_pairs
       {
         % Parens around each qualifier
         \msg_term:n{Pair~of~parens~around~each~item~in~#1~}
         \text{Pair~of~parens~around~each~item~in~#1~}
         \tl_show:N \l_tmpa_tl
         {
           (
           \msg_term:n{open~paren}
           \exists
           \msg_term:n{exists}
           \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_tl
           {
             )
             \exists
             (
           }
           \msg_term:n{seq_use}
           )
         }
      {#2}
         \msg_term:n {seq_us~ OK}
       }
       {
         \msg_term:n{No~multiple~parens~}
         \bool_if:NTF \style_qual_parens
           {
             %parens around string of qualifiers
             \msg_term:n{Single~pair~of~parens~for~#1~}
             (
             \tl_map_inline:Nn {#1}
               {
                 \exists {##1}
               }
             ) #2
           }
           {
             % Bare qualifier
             \msg_term:n{no~parens~for~#1~}
             \tl_map_inline:Nn {#1}
               {
                 \msg_term:n{item~##1~}
                 \exists ##1
               }
             {#2}
           }
       }
      }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[ \uqualg {{X}} {P(X)} \]

\[ \uqualg{{X}{Y}} {P(X,Y)} \]

\ExplSyntaxOn
\bool_gset_false:N \style_qual_paren_pairs
\bool_gset_true:N \style_qual_parens
\ExplSyntaxOff

\[ \uqualg {{X}} {P(X)} \]

\[ \uqualg{{X}{Y}} {P(X,Y)} \]

\ExplSyntaxOn
\bool_gset_true:N \style_qual_paren_pairs
\bool_gset_false:N \style_qual_parens
\ExplSyntaxOff

\[ \uqualg {{X}} {P(X)} \]

\[ \uqualg{{X}{Y}} {P(X,Y)} \]

\end{document}
```

Note: nothing in the `expl3` documentation of `\tl_show:N` suggests a
terminal read.

The error occurs in the call to `\seq_use:Nn` at line 43 inserting the
string `) \exists (`.

```
*************************************************
* Enterring uqualg
*************************************************
*************************************************
* No subscript for {X}{Y}
*************************************************
*************************************************
* l_tmpa_tl={X}{Y}
*************************************************
*************************************************
* test paren pairs
*************************************************
*************************************************
* Pair of parens around each item in {X}{Y}
*************************************************
> \l_tmpa_tl={X}{Y}.
<recently read> }

l.112 \[ \uqualg{{X}{Y}} {P(X,Y)}
                                  \]
?
*************************************************
* open paren
*************************************************
*************************************************
* exists
*************************************************
! Missing = inserted for \ifnum.
<to be read again>
                   {
l.112 \[ \uqualg{{X}{Y}} {P(X,Y)}
```

Comment: Why are you setting a token list variable to a sequence?

Comment: The code comes from the answer to another question, and seems to work in other contexts. I couldn't find an equivalent to \use_seq:Nn for token lists, and it seemed reasonable that there would be an automatic conversion. I also couldn't find a transfer function. However, taking another look at your code I see that you were using \seq_set_split:Nnn as a transfer function, so I'll try that.

Comment: I'll repeat myself: try and explain *precisely* what your aim is. There are many ways to skin a cat, so you can get better suggestions. Your code is confused and badly written.

Comment: My aim is to take a token list containing, e.g., {foo}{bar}{baz} and to emit (\exists foo) (\exists bar) (\exists baz). Are you suggesting that \tl_map_inline:Nn is a better way to do that?

Comment: Better yet, you could input the list more easily as `\uqualg{X,Y}{P(X,Y)}` and use `\clist_map_inline:nn`. The conditionals you set seem to be used for changing the style, and they require explanation, too.

Comment: The conditionals are a moving target; I'm considering changing the multiple Booleans to two strings, one selecting the parenthesis style as (NONE, SINGLE, MULTIPLE) and one selecting the subscript style as (NONE, STACKED, MULTIPLE). Currently I have \style_qual_parens for a single pair of parenthes around a string of quantifiers, \style_qual_paren_pairs for one pair of parentheses around each quantifier and \style_qual_subscript if the bound variable should be rendered as a subscript. IAC my Booleans are misnamed due to a finger check, so they will have to change.

Comment: I don't understand what you question is now that you've edited it. Originally, you wanted help re. errors. But if the code works, what is the question now? [Note that you shouldn't edit questions to include answers as it makes things very confusing!]

Comment: @cfr the remaining question is why  \tl_show:N and \int_show:N  are pausing for a terminal read when the expl3 documentation mentions no such behavior.

Comment: @cfr, See p. 107 of <http://mirrors.concertpass.com/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf>. The issue isn't writing to the terminal, it's pausing for a read from the terminal.

Comment: @shmuel Yes. Okular's search sometimes turns up nothing even when things are there, it seems. Thanks for the reference. But this really is just what `show` does. Compare `\show` and `\showdef` etc. They all work in the same way. See page 17 for an explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Does this satisfy you? I think you should clearly explain what you want to do.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand \uqualg { m m } { \shmuel_uqual:nn { #1 } { #2 } }
\NewDocumentCommand \setupuqualg { m } { \keys_set:nn { shmuel / uqualg } { #1 } }

\keys_define:nn { shmuel / uqualg }
 {
  subscript    .bool_gset:N = \g_uqual_scrpt_bool ,
  singleparens .bool_gset:N = \g_uqual_snglparen_bool ,
  multiparens  .bool_gset:N = \g_uqual_multparen_bool ,
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \math_sb:n #1 { \c_math_subscript_token { #1 } }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \shmuel_uqual:nn #1 #2
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { } { #1 }
  \bool_if:NTF \g_uqual_scrpt_bool
   {
    \bool_if:NT \g_uqual_snglparen_bool (
    \exists \math_sb:n { \substack { \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { \\ } } }
    \bool_if:NT \g_uqual_snglparen_bool )
   }
   {
    \bool_if:NTF \g_uqual_multparen_bool
     {
      ( \exists \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { ) ( \exists } )
     }
     {
      \bool_if:NT \g_uqual_snglparen_bool (
      \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { \exists ##1 }
      \bool_if:NT \g_uqual_snglparen_bool )
     }
   }
   #2
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[ \uqualg {X}  {P(X)}   \]
\[ \uqualg {XY} {P(X,Y)} \]

\setupuqualg{singleparens}

\[ \uqualg {X}  {P(X)}   \]
\[ \uqualg {XY} {P(X,Y)} \]

\setupuqualg{multiparens}

\[ \uqualg {X}  {P(X)}   \]
\[ \uqualg {XY} {P(X,Y)} \]

\setupuqualg{subscript}

\[ \uqualg {X}  {P(X)}   \]
\[ \uqualg {XY} {P(X,Y)} \]

\setupuqualg{subscript,singleparens=false}

\[ \uqualg {X}  {P(X)}   \]
\[ \uqualg {XY} {P(X,Y)} \]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'll have to think about the suggestion from @egreg to use clist. Also, there are some things that I don't understand about the code, e.g., why you define \math_sb instead of just using \sb. Some other things may become clear after I read the descriptions of the commands that you're using. Certainly your code seems to be more compact, which is good.

Comment: I would definitely use `\clist_map_inline:nn` as he says. I prefer `{a,x,q}` rather than `{axq}` (this one is cryptic) or `{{a}{x}{q}}` (this one is difficult to write and to read). `{a,x,q}` is simple, and clear. I define `\math_sb:n` to have an expl3 version of `\sb`. I'm using exactly your commands, except for may be the `l3keys` but you can forget about that, that's just an interface for setting the booleans, and may be the `T`(true) variants of `\bool_if:NT` rather than `TF` (true false).

Answer (score 1):

[This is just a supplement so I can format it properly. It answers the current question as explained in the comments on that question, rather than the original question which was addressed by Manuel.]

The explanation of what `_show` macros do is more detailed on page 17 when the first such example is introduced.

> ```
> \cs_show:N <control sequence>
> ```
>
> Displays the definition of the `<control sequence>` on the terminal.
>
> **TeXhackers note:** This is similar to the TeX primitive `\show`, wrapped to a fixed number of characters per line.

So the behaviour is expected to be similar to that of `\show` and friends, which all pause compilation in order to *show* something on the terminal.